# org.edx.mobile.view.RegisterActivity: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException

Tags: android, android-studio, ssl, sslhandshakeexception, openedx

I am trying to configure the Open edX Android app https://github.com/edx/edx-app-android using Android Studio.

The point given below is also set.

- Create `edx.properties` inside the `OpenEdXMobile` directory.

  ```
  edx.dir = '../../my_config'
  ```
- Create `edx.properties` inside the `my_config` directory.

  ```
  edx.android {
     configFiles = ['android.yaml']
  }
  ```
- Create `android.yaml` file inside the `my_config` directory.

  ```
  API_HOST_URL: 'https://org.mylms.com'
  ENVIRONMENT_DISPLAY_NAME: 'Training Potal'
  OAUTH_CLIENT_ID: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  PLATFORM_NAME: 'Training'
  USER_PROFILES_ENABLED: 'true'
  PLATFORM_DESTINATION_NAME: 'org.mylms.com'
  ```
- Create `gradle.properties` file inside the `OpenEdXMobile` directory.

  ```
  APPLICATION_ID=org.edx.mobile
  RELEASE_STORE_FILE=../../openedx.keystore
  RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=mystorepassword
  RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=mykeypassword
  RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=openedx_alias
  ```

I am getting below error while clicking on the registration in the Android App.

```
E/org.edx.mobile.view.RegisterActivity: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:219)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:188)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:145)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:108)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
    at org.edx.mobile.http.interceptor.NewVersionBroadcastInterceptor.intercept(NewVersionBroadcastInterceptor.java:44)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
    at org.edx.mobile.http.interceptor.OauthHeaderRequestInterceptor.intercept(OauthHeaderRequestInterceptor.java:36)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
    at org.edx.mobile.http.interceptor.UserAgentInterceptor.intercept(UserAgentInterceptor.java:21)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:646)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:197)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:399)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.doHandshake(SslWrapper.java:374)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:217)
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:188) 
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:145) 
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:108) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198) 
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187) 
    at org.edx.mobile.http.interceptor.NewVersionBroadcastInterceptor.intercept(NewVersionBroadcastInterceptor.java:44) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187) 
    at org.edx.mobile.http.interceptor.OauthHeaderRequestInterceptor.intercept(OauthHeaderRequestInterceptor.java:36) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187) 
    at org.edx.mobile.http.interceptor.UserAgentInterceptor.intercept(UserAgentInterceptor.java:21) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127) 
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:646) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339) 
    at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94) 
    at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:197) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:399) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.SslWrapper.doHandshake(SslWrapper.java:374) 
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:217) 
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:188) 
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:145) 
    at okhttp3.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:108) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:188) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:127) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:241) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:240) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198) 
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:203) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187) 
    at org.edx.mobile.http.interceptor.NewVersionBroadcastInterceptor.intercept(NewVersionBroadcastInterceptor.java:44) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187) 
    at org.edx.mobile.http.interceptor.OauthHeaderRequestInterceptor.intercept(OauthHeaderRequestInterceptor.java:36) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187) 
    at org.edx.mobile.http.interceptor.UserAgentInterceptor.intercept(UserAgentInterceptor.java:21) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:187) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127) 
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Resolved, I am getting this error due to my LMS SSL certificate not trusted. Thank you